# How to print out changes to a list and then print out the original?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

In this snippet of code, I would like to make changes to a list, print it out, and then print out the original. I am changing listB, and leaving listC alone. But when I run this code, listC also gets changed for some reason. How can I fix this?

```
listB = [1,2,3,4,5]
listC = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(listB)
print(listC)
a = 0
while a<100:
    listB[0] = a
    print(listB)
    listB = listC
    print(listB)
    print(listC)
    a+=1
```

Comment: `listB = listC` makes `listB` reference the same list as `listC`.  You can try using `listB = listC.copy()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two or more lists are assigned like

```
list1=list2
```

They are referring to same location.

So when one of the list changes, another list also changes to same

So It's better to have copy list

Try this code

```
listB = [1,2,3,4,5]
listC = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(listB)
print(listC)
a = 0
while a<100:
    listB[0] = a
    print(listB)
    listB = listC.copy()
    print(listB)
    print(listC)
    a+=1
```

This code just copies the elements of ListC rather than referencing

So listC stays original ever

Comment: When I use the .copy(), my terminal says that list doesn't have the attribute .copy(). What should I do?

Comment: When I execute the same above code with python3 it working super perfect, which version of python you are running with?

Comment: If you don't find copy doesn't work anymore then try this.  listB = list(listC)